# HighCharts tooltip issue

Tags: highcharts

im using a common function to generate linechart using highchart.for certain charttype i want tooltip without any pointformat and for another in want to use formatter funcction how to acheive this.From the below code charttype 1 tooltip diappear.

> tooltip: {
>                       valueSuffix: '',
>                       pointFormat: (chartType == 1 ? '{series.name}:
>   **{point.y}**
> ' : '' ) ,
>                       shared: (chartType == 1 ? true : false),
>
> ```
>                 formatter: function() {
>                     if (chartType == 2) {
>                         return '' + this.point.tooltip + ': ' + (chartType == 2 ? this.y.toFixed(1) : this.y.toFixed(0));
>                     } 
>                     else {
>                         return false;
>                     }
>                 }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable option, use `null` value, not empty string (`''`). See: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/133/

However I think that it would be better to add one if-else statement, instead of three one above another, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/134/

```
    var chartType = 1,
        tooltip = {
            valueSuffix: ''
        };

    if (chartType == 1) {
        tooltip.pointFormat = '{series.name}: {point.y}';
        tooltip.shared = true;
    } else {
        tooltip.shared = false;
        tooltip.formatter = function () {
            if (chartType == 2) {
                return '' + this.point.tooltip + ': ' + (chartType == 2 ? this.y.toFixed(1) : this.y.toFixed(0));
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then create chart:

```
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        tooltip: tooltip,
        // other options
    });
```